# Windows batch command ftp

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

is there anyone who can tell me how to make a batch which connects to at ftp server and downloads the latest file from the server.

I only need the newest file, not the old ones.

Comment: How are the files named?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) for Windows, which can be configured to download only newer files than those you currently have, like this:

`wget -N ftp://username%3Apassword@FTPServerAddress/dir/*`

Comment: windows has it's own built in ftp client - `ftp.exe`. The hard part is date comparison. and wget does not help much...

Comment: wget -m ftp://username:password@1.2.3.4/dir/* does the date comparison, you must have - of course - the older version on your local drive. But maybe your question is, how to download all files which are newer than a specific date? The latest is a quite relative term.

Answer (score 0):

check [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/054e0329-2439-4811-9a49-02a121c9b843/powershell-ftp-download-newest-files).It requires powershell (all windows 7 machines have it by default).It's juest easier to compare dates with it.